# Azure Function with Cosmos Db Group By clause

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I need to use the GROUP BY clause for cosmos query, and I am using Azure Function App 2.0.

For which I am facing the issue of `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: orderedAliases.`

Here is the query which I am referring to:

> select sq.id, COUNT(sq.id) as QueueCount
>   FROM queueStatus as c JOIN sq IN c.subQueue WHERE sq.id not in (5,8) and c.facilityId = @FacilityId
>   group by sq.id

I understood that Azure Cosmos DB currently supports GROUP BY in .NET SDK 3.3 and above, and I am currently using the latest .Net SDK 3.6.

Is there anyone who encountered such an issue?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show your query. As written, you haven't included this, so any answer would just be a guess. Also: have you tried writing the query and running it independently (outside of your Azure Function), via the portal, to see if it works as designed?

Comment: I have added a query, for which I am facing the issue.
Also, I have tried with the console app, where it's working as expected.

Comment: I have tried with the latest version of .Net SDK also, which is `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.6` but still the issue persists.

Comment: Can you paste the actual code doing the query? Or are you using the Azure Functions `[CosmosDB]` bindings?

Comment: @PurveshDesai This might be related to: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/974